# azure walinuxagent: no package available on oracle linux 6.5

Tags: linux, oracle, azure, agent

I'm trying to follow this guide http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-create-upload-vhd-oracle/ to prepare my virtual machine for uploading on azure.

I'm arrived at the command "sudo yum install WALinuxAgent" and given it but obtained the error "No package WALinuxAgent available"; I also updated the file public-yum-ol6.repo and checked for update to 6 update 5 but without result.

Where I can find it (over then github)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from [OpenLogic's EL6 repo](http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/openlogic/6/openlogic/x86_64/RPMS/). WALinuxAgent doesn't seem to be in Oracle Linux public yum repos.

Comment: On Azure documentation there is a page where it is indicated that there is a package in Oracle repos: maybe Microsoft must correct that information or provide a link to that package/repo.


Marco Mangiante